# How to open monaco editor find and replace using a javscript function?

Tags: javascript, replace, find, monaco-editor

Is there any way I could open the Find and replace box using a javascript function suppose like `function x(){ editor.trigger('keyboard','openFindWidget');}`  This code is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use an action for that:

```
                editor?.focus();
                const action = editor?.getAction("actions.find");
                void action?.run();
```

Comment: hey thanks for the help but I am using javascript I had actually tagged this question as javascript. I had also specified it as a javascript function

Comment: but I don't know why it is not working. I tried many different ways like changing the variables. and much more but it does not work.